# Install gradle version 3.4.1 on qt version 5.9 (for work with java 9.0.1)

Tags: qt, gradle, build

I use Qt 5.9 for android application and for build app I enable Use `gradle instead of And` aslo I use `jdk-9.0.1` and `ndk -r 16` now when run build program The Qt automatic download gradle 4.3  from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-bin.zip

**My problem Is**: the gradle 4.3 not recognize jdk 9.0.1 and i get this

**error : Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'.**

I shoud instal gradle new version (4.3.1) to work with jdk 9.0.1 !!

but download and install gradle is automatic and Qt do that !!

**how its posible to solve this problem and install gradle 4.3.1 !! and make QT use this version ??**

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and solved it this way:

Inside your build directory androiddeployqt automatically creates a gradle folder. Edit the following file in a text editor:

gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties

Replace the version 3.4.1 in the line:

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-bin.zip

with the version you want, for example 4.3
The bug is indeed solved in this newer version of gradle.